# Interpreting 2 dimensional kernel density estimates ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created several 2-dimensional kernel density estimates using ggplot.  I have been using the following code:

```
m <- ggplot(EMOD29, aes(x=GPP, y=ER, shape=Model)) +
geom_point(aes(shape=Model, color=Model), size=3.5)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(3,16)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("Black","Black"))+
theme(legend.title = element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(size=15, "Times New 
Roman"), legend.position = "right", aspect.ratio = 1)+
xlim(0, 25) +
ylim(-10,5)+
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1)))

KDE.plot.m<- m + stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", contour = TRUE,
              aes(fill = after_stat(level)), colour="transparent",
              bins = 30)+
geom_point() +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=18),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(),
    legend.position = "right")

KDE.plot.m
```

The code successfully creates a plot, however, I cannot find any clear answer as to what *levels* actually mean. Are they related to probability? How should this be interpreted?

[image]

Comment: The level shown on the plot is the 2D _probability density function_. It is not the same thing as probability, but it _is_ related. If you imagine the x, y plane, then the probability density function is a curved surface that sits above that plane. The _volume_ under any particular region of this surface gives the actual probability that a random draw will fall within that region of the plane. In other words, the probability is the double integral of the density function. The total volume under the surface is equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response! So, to add to this, when comparing 2 different density plots, is it fair to say that a density plot with a higher level value (i.e., the darkest blue area has a value of 0.8 as opposed to 0.1) has a higher volume underneath, which would mean there's a greater chance a random point would fall under the value of 0.8 as opposed to a 0.1 value?

Comment: That's only true if you take the area into account. If the two areas are the same size, then yes, there is a 4x greater probability of the point falling in the area with the higher level. However, a small region with a level of 0.8 could still be less likely to have a point inside it if the region with a level of 0.2 was more than 4 times the area of the 0.8 region. The level gives you the relative likliehood at any specific point on the plane, so that you are 4 times as likely to find a random point where the level is 0.8 as you are where the level is 0.2.

Comment: That makes sense. Adding more points or changing the scale would likely take away the ability to easily compare 2 separate plots. Thank you so much for your help!